# mgwt side navigation / menu

Tags: navigation, mgwt

Is there a full example or is it even possbile to display a side navigation in mgwt like :

[this](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/06/emerging-ui-pattern-side-navigation.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SwipeMenu.

Try this example:

https://code.google.com/p/mgwt/source/browse/examples/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mgwt/examples/client/SwipeMenuExample.java?repo=examples